# Materialize css loading after my styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code is like -

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->       
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection" />

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen,projection" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>

        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>      
    </body>
  </html>
```

As you can see my `href="css/style.css"` is after the `href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"` but in browser materialize css is overriding my `style.css` Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

I applied `btn_apply` class on an anchor tag but somehow materialize classes/css are getting the priorities every time. Let me know how I can fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style in `materialize.min.css` is taking priority because it matches **two** classes `.btn.disabled`, but your style only matches **one** class `.btn_apply`. Change yours to

```
.btn.btn_apply {
    ...
}
```

Then it will match the same number of classes, and take precedence because the file was loaded later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works btw do I need to use !important every time in overriding the css like - `.btn.btn_apply {
 background: #FFFFFF !important;
 border: 1px solid #9F9F9F !important;
}` is working but  `.btn.btn_apply {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
}` not

Comment: You should generally try to avoid using `!important`. Only use it when there's no other way to make your selector take precedence. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.btn` prefix to your `.btn_apply` class. It's overridden because button has multiple classes `btn, disabled`.

So your `btn_apply` should look like

```
.btn.btn_apply{  // <== prefix

 }
```

```css
.btn{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn_apply{
  background: blue;
}
.btn_apply{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">.btn</button><br>
<button class="btn btn_apply">.btn.btn_apply</button><br>
<button class="btn_apply">.btn_apply</button>
```